# php die() equivalent code in asp

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am learning asp . In php we use

```
die('error message')
```

**what is its equivalent code in asp (vb script )? How to debug in asp?**

Comment: Why learn classic ASP now? I advise you learn ASP.NET.

Comment: which server are you one? Opening an access database with he Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver is not possible on all servers.. Try first to add an ***On error resume next*** statement and see if you then have your equivalent of php's die().. If you have confirmation you had an error, use the error object to learn more:       ***if err.number <> 0 then : response.write Err.Description : end if***

Comment: thanx AardVark. Can I connect mysql with classic asp?

Comment: @deepak: yes you can connect to mysql from classic asp. use the myodbc driver from mysql site (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) and a connection string from connectionstrings.com (http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#mysql-connector-odbc-5-1)

Comment: @deepak I rolled back your last edit regarding database connections, because it is too different from your original question. If it is still an issue, please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 15):

In Classic ASP, Use this:

```
Response.End
```

---

To output something before ending, use this code:

```
Response.Write "Hello, World!"
Response.End
```

This is equivalent to:

```
die("Hello, World!");
```

Comment: I am not getting output return from this script. As you said I wrote your line at end

Comment: <%

DIM objConn
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  Source=" & _  
Server.MapPath ("data/northwind.mdb") & ";" 
objConn.Open
Response.Write "Hello, World!"
Response.End
%>

Comment: @deepak What is the response you are getting?

Comment: You need to be more specific. In IIS, there are minor error details like 500.XX, so saying that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remeber very much about asp.net but you can use

> return *your variable here*

or

```
Response.End
```

The second one will output everythings